# gulp sass is not working showing error

Tags: gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

[image]

showing me this error don't know how to resolve it.

my gulpfile.js code is as follow

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
gulp.task('default', function(){
   gulp.src('js/*.js')
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('minjs'));
});
//style task
gulp.task('styles', function(){
   gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass())
   .pip(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this hasn't been resolved there is a spelling mistake in the styles task. On the last line it says:

`pip(gulp.dest('css/'));`

I assume this needs to be:

`pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));`

Give that a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Your gulp task would probably work with [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) but you're using [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) which isn't the same. Note the `gulp-ruby-sass` documentation:

```
gulp.task('sass', () =>
  sass('source/file.scss') // not .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('result'))
);
```